# is there a formula to count the values in a column which give an absolute value result of 1 when the values in another column are subtracted

Tags: excel, excel-formula, comparison

Abt. 30 integer values in range say 1 to 1000 fill one column and same is true for a second column. Some of these numbers give an absolute value of 1 when subtracted from each-other.
Say 587 is in one column and 588 in the other. |587-588|=1. I need to find how many of these numbers are in one of the two columns.

Without a formula I have to try 30x30=900 times for each number in one column, store the conditional result as say 1/0 and count the ones but it is tedious.

Comment: So it is not a row by row match, but each number in one column needs to be compared to each number in the second to see if there is a difference of 1 between them?  Also what happens if one number in the first column has more than one number that is 1 away from it?  does it count as 1 or 2?

Comment: Thanks so much for your help and indeed, that's the case. Valid point, for any number 'n' in the first column, the second column may contain both the n+1 and n-1 values and if so, I need to count them both. The second formula below nicely manages to count both of them!

Comment: You can remove the `>0` and the outer `()` from the first formula to achieve the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `COUNTIFS`:

```
=(COUNTIFS($B$1:$B$30,A1+1)+COUNTIFS($B$1:$B$30,A1-1))>0
```

[image]

If you need the exact number:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(B:B,">="&A1:A30-1,B:B,"<="&A1:A30+1,B:B,"<>"&A1:A30))
```

which would return `2` with the above sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to compare each number in column A to each number in column B? If so, you could try transposing those numbers across the columns, then do `=--(ABS(A3#-B2#)=1)`

[image: Conditional formatted where absolute value of difference equals 1]